# Letting a PHP ternary operator refer to itself

Tags: php

I sometimes get very tired that PHP always wants it's fully reference in a ternary operator, giving your horrors like these;

```
$qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] = ($qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] === 1 ? $qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] : '0');
```

Is there a way to simply put refer to the current modified variable (object)? For example;

```
$qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] = (self === 1 ? self ? '0');
```

Please don't look at the code itself. It's not about the example's code working. It's purely about the possiblity of a SELF-reference without an extra modification. A `DEFINE` method would be nice too, but I guess PHP can't make complex `DEFINE`s like, for example, Objective-C can.

Also I'm aware of styles like so;

```
foreach ($qb->records as $k => &$v) { ... }
```

..but I dont' want that method in a pre-defined state.

Comment: `($qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] === 1 ? : '0');` is perfectly valid in the more recent versions of [PHP (>= 5.3)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: as is also explained [in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (>= 5.3)

Comment: Very true Mark, but it's ugly. I'm used to Pythonic programming, and this is like the most anti-that possible. In essence a String is an `object` right? I understand with PHP that's different, but shouldn't a self-reference be possible?

Comment: @NDM true, but what if I have more (and deeper) statements? I still lose the capability to refer to the variable itself in a shorted reference-matter.

Comment: in php, a string in **not** an object!

Comment: what about ($qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] === 1 ? 1 : '0' ); I know what you are asking is different thing, but it reduces the mess

Comment: @MarkBaker: Not an answer, that will eval to boolean true instead of 1 if the comparison succeeds. Comparing with anything other than 1 would immediately introduce a bug.

Comment: So in essence, what does the C-code (source) state that a universal variable in PHP is? There should be some way to reference that piece of memory.

Comment: @Jon, you are right - was so happy to learn something new I have wanted for a long time, but `$a=3; echo $a==3 ? : 7;` produces `1` :(

Answer (score 5):

To answer the original question:

**In PHP you can not reference the variable you are assigning the value to, as you apparently would in Python or other languages.**

That being said, in PHP 5.3 they is a way to shorten the ternary operator in certain usages. From the [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator.
>
> Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns `expr1` if `expr1` evaluates to
>   `TRUE`, and `expr3` otherwise.

So you could use something like:

```
$result = ($qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] ?: 0);
```

if you want the value from `$qb->records[$k]['Claimed']` when that value evaluates to `TRUE`.

Also, strictly relating to the original code example, where the `value === 1` comparison was used, and without having anything to do with the ternary operator, you could rewrite the condition as:

```
$result = (int) ($qb->records[$k]['Claimed'] === 1);
```

This will return `1` when `$qb->records[$k]['Claimed']` is `1`, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: I still think this is not what OP wants. He wrote he needs something like that `(self === 1 ? self ? '0');`.  What if example was `(self === 'string' ? self . 'extra' : 0);`? OP is talking about `SELF-reference`, whatever the `if` stetement looks like...

Comment: @Glavić I provided a second example that behaves the same way as `(self === 1 ? self : 0)`. For the example you provided I don't think there's any possible optimization.

Comment: This appears to be the closest an answer can get to nailing that question. Myself, I didn't know this tidbit, and it's quite useful. Kudos.

Comment: The second example works **only** if you are comparing to 1 (all other comparisons will introduce bugs), so I don't see how it's useful. The first example does not do what the question asks for.

Comment: @Jon That's true, it's only useful as a means to rewrite the original provided example, that had a `value === 1` comparison. It's not really meant as a means to optimize the ternary operator in general.

Comment: @dcro: Well, the question says "Please don't look at the code itself. It's not about the example's code working. It's purely about the possiblity of a SELF-reference without an extra modification." -- hence my critique.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but as explained the example is not leading. It's purely about the reference to the working variable itself. I wish there was some way to let PHP make all variables `Object`s by default so we can reference to them and even adjust them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to make a function which does the trick:

```
function setval(&$val, $desired, $default) {
    if ($val != $desired) {
        $val = $default;
    }
}
```

`$val` is passed by reference, so it is affected by the function; `$desired` is the desired value of the comparison; `$default` is the value when the desired value is not met.

**Example:**

```
setval($qb->records[$k]['Claimed'], 1, '0');
```

For the rest indeed: the `condition ?: else` shorthand if-else is the closest you'll get...

Comment: I thought that too. But this needs a lot more extension to be reasonable as an all-round Helper-function. You would need to imply a recurring function that can catch endless parameters and can know how to call `defined` globals to traverse to it's parent and absolute variable. A `ME` definition or something similar could then act as the reference to the initial variable. I think the real answer would lie to adjust the PHP source code and recompiling it a custom functionality. Sadly this dependency makes it annoying to move the code to other servers, without doing a full recompile in WHM.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not much you can do.

The best I could ever get was introducing a temporary variable inline, which reduces the number of occurrences of your initial variable from three to two. For example:

```
$arr = ['foo' => ['bar' => 2]];

// Introducing $_ -- the parens are needed!
$arr['foo']['bar'] = ($_ = $arr['foo']['bar']) === 2 ? $_ : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELF-referenced` pointer like you described doesn't exist. If you want shorter code, you can save long-named variable reference into new variable `$v` and use that variable in your `if` statements:

```
$qb['records']['k']['Claimed'] = 'test';
$v = &$qb['records']['k']['Claimed'];

$v = $v === 'test' ? $v . ' extra' : null;
unset($v);

print_r($qb);
```

Answer (score -1):

Objective-C `#define` is a [macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) construct that uses stuff from the current context to allow you to define various shortcuts including defining constants, defining things that look like functions (but are actually replaced by other code).

PHP `define()` is a function with the sole purpose of initializing constants.

The only PHP shorthand for what you want to accomplish is the short form of the ternary operator `$x ?: NULL`.